# NET SEND to users Across Network

Tags: c#, winapi, com

Not sure how to phrase this again, but... this is what I'm trying to do:

I'm writing a program to scan for duplicate logged on users (Users logged on more than once) on my network at work.

I can write the duplicity finder, but I need a way to be able to send a message out to that user saying they aren't allowed to be logged on more than once on the network and this message needs to go to each computer they're logged in on.

I've tried "net send  " but it appears to be only sent to one computer. (I'm sitting here logged in three times testing this and I only get 1/3 three messages. :/)

Thanks,
-Zack

Comment: How are you using net send?  Are you using the command three times to send it to each individual machine?

Comment: I thought "net send <user> <message>" would send it to each computer that is logged in as said "<user>"..perhaps I'm wrong?

Comment: Isn't Net Send disabled by default in WinXP SP2+? I would expect it would be disabled on most Windows OSes since then. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839018

Comment: On this network, it's enabled because it's how we let users know they're low on funds for printing. (just clearing that up)

Anyway, I think I got it worked out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering an old question of mine that doesn't have an answer.

If I were tackling this problem again, I would likely setup a local daemon or application to receive push-style notifications for Windows 7 or likely look into [WNS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview) for Windows 10 apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also net send to computers - have you tried that?

Comment: This is what I was thinking.  Send it to each computer instead of username.